# core data fetched property. refresh after update

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data

I have UITableView with NSFetchedResultsController and a main context attached to it.
I'm updating my main context from background.

```
- (void)contextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context=[self managedObjectContext];
    [context performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:) withObject:notification waitUntilDone:YES];

    if ([context hasChanges])
    {            
        [context performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(save:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

    }        
}
```

My UITableView reloads with new data and everything is fine, *but* some UITableView cell's data must be populated from fetched properties and I need that values to be refreshed.

I've read about NSManagedObjectContext's method refreshObject:mergeChanges: that might help. Where should I place it? If I will place it in cellForRowAtIndexPath's helper method - configureCell:atIndexPath: this will result in cycling row updates.

Here's the piece of cell configuration code:

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)theIndexPath
{
    //NSLog(@"PTAgencyList: configureCell: atIndexPath: %i %i", theIndexPath.section, theIndexPath.row);

    NSManagedObject *managedObj=[self.agenciesFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:theIndexPath];
    if (managedObj==nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"PANIC: fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: returned nil object");
        return;
    }
    else
    {

        CDAgency *agency=(CDAgency *)managedObj;

        [agency city];
        NSLog(@"agency.city_server_id: %@", agency.city_server_id);
        NSLog(@"agency.city.name: %@", ((CDCities *)[[agency city] objectAtIndex:0]).name);
        NSFetchRequest *fr=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [fr setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Cities" inManagedObjectContext:self.context]];
        [fr setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"server_id=%@", agency.city_server_id]];
        NSArray *res=[self.context executeFetchRequest:fr error:nil];
        NSLog(@"fetched city name: %@", ((CDCities *)[res objectAtIndex:0]).name);
```

After context update:
fetched property city is nil (I think it is because it still points to the old city entry that was removed), *but* if I'm doing the fetch manually I'm getting fresh data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call your fetched property explicitly where you configure your cell.

```
[managedObject fetchedPropertyAttribute];
```

It should recompute as expected.

Also, consider using a **relationship** rather than a fetched property.

Comment: Please feel free to ask me questions

Comment: A fetch request in configure cell is almost certainly wrong. You should use the object returned by your fetched results controller.

Comment: You need to examine exactly what happens when you call `city`.

Comment: I'm using it. I've added FetchRequest to cell configuration method to ensure that agency's city data is not nil after update

Comment: It seems to me that our use of fetched property is not appropriate. Why not use a relationship?

Comment: I'm pulling my fetched property with predicate: SELF.server_id=$FETCH_SOURCE.city_server_id and getting a response. This response gets cached somehow and if the data updates I need to refetch this property because the data becomes not fresh

Comment: I must have "loosely coupled" relationships to avoid synchronization conflicts. Apple documentation recommends to use fetched properties in such situations: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html

Comment: Re-reading the documentation, I am more convinced that fetched properties are inappropriate in your situation. Rather, you should update your data when new information comes from the server.